# Can't use send-mailmessage when using PSFTP Module

Tags: email, powershell, session, ftp

I've made a Powershell script which uploads data to a NAS.
After the Upload is completed the script should send an Email message.

When the script tries to send a mailmessage I get an error saying I used an incorrect security certificate.

This error only shows up when I use the PSFTP module. When i run the sendmail code on its own it works just fine.

The FTP session itself isn't alive anymore so this shouldn't be a problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction to sort this problem out?I've made a Powershell script which uploads data to a NAS.
After the Upload is completed the script should send an Email message.

When the script tries to send a mailmessage I get an error saying I used an incorrect security certificate.

This error only shows up when I use the PSFTP module. When i run the sendmail code on its own it works just fine.

The FTP session itself isn't alive anymore so this shouldn't be a problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction to sort this problem out?

```
    $Execution = Get-ExecutionPolicy

    If($Execution -eq "RemoteSigned")
    {
       Write-Host "HOI" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 
    } 
    Else
    {
       Set-ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned 
    }
1.Module PSFTP importing 
    Import-Module PSFTP

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “Wachtwoord” -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential   (“Admin”, $secpasswd)

    Variables 

    $Session = "Alive"
    $ftp = "IP" 
    $Credentials = "Admin"
    $FtpFile = "C:\Test\Back-up.ps1"
    $ftpDestination = "FTPLOCATIE"

2.Connect to FTP with module PSFTP 

    Set-FTPConnection -Server $ftp -Credentials $mycreds -Session $Session
    ( Connect to ftp) 
3.TPItem for uploading to NAS 

    Get-ChildItem $FtpFile | Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $ftpDestination -Overwrite

4.Section for mailing,variables 

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “Wachtwoord” -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycredsMail = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“Email-address”, $secpasswd)

5. Section for mailing

        $Smtp = "smtp.office365.com"
        $Port = "587"
        $To   = "Email"
        $Subject = "Back-up"
        $From = "Email 

6. this is where i want send the mail i use ssl 

        Send-MailMessage -to $To -from $From -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $Smtp -Credential $mycredsMail -Port $Port -UseSsl
```

Comment: What happens if you `remove-module psftp` immediately before calling `send-mailmessage`?

Comment: Just tried that, without success ( same error)  Thanks for the suggestion